# Multiple Composite Component with Backing Bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean, composite-component

I have a JSF Composite Component with complex behavior, and which has a Backing Bean to hold and process data.
I can use this component normally if I place it only one time whitin then xhtml. But I have problem setting the component multiple times per page, since all the components will use the same reference of Backing Bean.

There's a way to have a single instance per component instantiation?

I can make it work if I create manually multiple instances of the Bean and pass all dependencies to them, and assign them to the components.
I'm actually searching a solution where the components are able to hold their data on their own.

Comment: This question is strange. Why in earth needing a backing bean if you already have the custom component itself? Perhaps you're confusing "custom components" with "composite components" and you *actually* have a composite component? If so, lookup "backing component".

Comment: Oh Lord. You're right, i've mixed the words. Looking for it right now, thanks.